# C# first element of string is missing

Tags: c#, string

I wrote a program, what is compute the difference of two string or compute a hamming distance.

I run in debug mode. And I saw, the at the `string first` the first element of string is missing. But the `string second` is good!

*When I tested the first's length and second's length is equal.*

**Forexample:**
I typed this: 00011
And in debug mode it's value only: 0011
. Or I typed this: "this", in debug the real value is only "his"

*Somebody can explain me, why missing the first element of string?*

**The code:**

```
    while (Console.Read() != 'X')
    {
            string first = Console.ReadLine();
            string second = Console.ReadLine();

            int distance = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
            {
                if (first[i]!= second[i])
                {
                    ++distance;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hamming distance is {0}.", distance);
        }
```

I tried modify the iteration, forexample the loop was ++i, or the first[i-1] but these aren't solve my problem.

Comment: Watch out for index out of bounds if second is shorter than first...

Comment: It could have something to do with your `Console.Read()` call as well. Try changing that to `Console.ReadLine() != @"X"` instead.

Comment: I have tested only when the first's and second's lenght is equal

Comment: I tried this: Console.ReadLine() != @"X", but the programe read this X charachter to the `string second`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Console.Read()` reads the first character from the buffer. This character will not be included in the `ReadLine()`.

I would personally find a better way to end your program such as if `first=="quit"` or by some other syntaxic means.

Comment: Can you give me an example for the ending? I have tried, but my program now always read an extra line

Answer (score 0):

You consume the first char with Console.Read() so it will not appear in first:

```
string first = Console.ReadLine();
while ((first != null) && (first[0] != 'X'))
{            
        string second = Console.ReadLine();

        int distance = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
        {
            if (first[i]!= second[i])
            {
                ++distance;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Hamming distance is {0}.", distance);
        first = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in vb.net and found out that it was causing by **"console.readkey()"**. console should only read one at time.See you have multiple read function at same time.

like **Readkey()** at **main()** and **readline()** on Background.thread...

Comment: this most likely a comment. not an answer

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace_File_Handling
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
         {

            string path = @"E:\File.txt";
            StreamReader r1 = new StreamReader(path);
            string m = r1.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(m);
            Console.ReadKey();
            r1.Close();
            StreamWriter wr = File.AppendText(path);
            string na = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
             wr.WriteLine(na);
            wr.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(na);
            Console.ReadKey();

            StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(path);
            string val = rd.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(val);

            rd.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```